# Java split array numbers

Tags: java

So I am trying to take numbers `123456789` and print them out like `123-456-789`. I am trying  to do something with the substring like `numbers[0].substring(0,2) + "-" + numbers[0].substring(3,5)` and so on... Here is what I have thus far.

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(reader);

String inputValue;

inputValue = input.readLine();
String[] numbers = inputValue.split("\\s+");

// This part here is incorrect but this is similar to the idea I am trying to do

System.out.print(numbers[0].substring(0,2) + "-" + 
                 numbers[0].substring(3,5) + "-" +
                 numbers[0].substring(6,8));
```

I am continually getting this error = Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8

Comment: What is not working? Do you get errors? What are they? What do you expect to happen and what is happening?

Comment: To add more informations to your question use [edit] option placed below your post. As your question is currently it is very unclear what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

From the Javadoc for String.substring

> public String substring(int beginIndex,
>                           int endIndex)
>
> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified
>   beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus
>   the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.

The end of the range is exclusive so you need

```
System.out.print(numbers[0].substring(0,3) + "-" + 
             numbers[0].substring(3,6) + "-" +
             numbers[0].substring(6,9));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then you might do it with something like

```
String inputValue = "123456789";
if (inputValue.length() == 9 && inputValue.matches("\\d+")) {
    String a = inputValue.substring(0, 3);
    String b = inputValue.substring(3, 6);
    String c = inputValue.substring(6);
    System.out.printf("%s-%s-%s%n", a, b, c);
} else {
    System.out.println("Could not format: " + inputValue);
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
123-456-789
```

Comment: Lets say that I want to enter several different tries like the first time `123456789` printing out 123-456-789 then doing something like `987654321` printing out 987-654-321.

Comment: @HelloWorld My example was only to demonstrate how you might format the `String inputValue`. I suggest you use a loop if you wish to process multiple lines of *input*, however each invocation might invoke the logic I have posted... you might even extract it into a `static` method that operates on a passed parameter `inputValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Peter's answer above should be accepted, but if you wanted to do it the quick and dirty way, you could convert the string to a character array, then use a loop that prints the numbers in sets of 3, followed by a hyphen.  Of course, you'd have to implement any error checking you think you'd need.